# Query Context for Inserted but yet Uncommitted records

Tags: c#, .net, linq, oracle

I've searched and searched stackoverflow and www, but have found no answers to this question.

I am looping through a number of records and under certain conditions I'm inserting new records into table A. Then I'm looping again on another data source (which cannot be merged with the first one), and if that be the case, I want to insert new records into the same table A. I only want to commit the records at the end of the process, but it'll give a primary key violation error if I just insert them.

Note: linq is not managing primary keys. Probably because I'm sort of a noob with linq and don't really know how to get linq to work with Oracle sequences.

My question is how do I check the existing context for the records I have inserted. This is what I am doing.

```
foreach(var rec in recordList1)
{
   ...
   dataContext.InsertOnSubmit(obj);
}

foreach(var rec in recordList2)
{
   if ( ! [check context here for existing record] )
   {
      ...
      dataContext.InsertOnSubmit(obj);
   }
}
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

I've tried querying the context in different ways, but it'll only return committed values.

Thanks in advance!
Best regards.

Comment: Not sure I completely understand the question but would using TransactionScope be your solution?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx

Comment: No. Justin's answer is what I was looking for. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the objects inserted, updated, deleted in the datacontext you need to call GetChangeSet.

```
var changed = dataContext.GetChangeSet();
var inserted = changed.Inserts;
var updated = changed.Updates;
var deleted = changed.Deletes;
```